# SEVERE: Invalid keystore format java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: format, keystore

I am trying to connect a https server running in Tibco in linux environment. I have created the keystore in linux environment using jdk 1.6.0.

Now I want a standalone http(s) client to connect to the server. I have downloaded the keystore generated (psaserver.keystore) and certificate (psaserver.cer) to the windows local system. My jdk version in the local system is also 1.6.

But when I try to connect I am getting this error:

```
Mar 31, 2011 7:14:03 PM com.sa.http.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory createSSLContext
SEVERE: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at com.sa.http.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createKeyStore(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:137)
    at com.sa.http.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSSLContext(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:192)
    at com.sa.http.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.getSSLContext(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.sa.http.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.sa.sim.GenericHTTPClient.run(GenericHTTPClient.java:76)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have gone through the queries regarding the same problem. Retried the same by creating the key so  many times, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem with the mode of ftp transfer. I did it with Binary mode now and its working fine.

Thanks,
Brinal